# gluUnproject on GL_Points or finding the depth coordinates from mouse coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, opengl-compat

I have a scene consisting of a lot of points which I drew using

```
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
glVertex3f(x[i],y[i],z[i]); // the points are displayed properly .. 
glEnd();
```

What I wish to do is to be able to click on one of the points on the scene using the mouse and get its 3-D coordinate.

I have seen other threads to use :

```
glReadPixels((GLdouble)mouse_x, 
    (GLdouble) (rect.Height()-mouse_y-1),1, 1,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &Z);
```

and use the value of z in

```
gluUnProject(mouse_x, mouse_y, 0, modelview, projection, viewport, out posX, out posY, out posZ);
```

but i always get `z=0` as the output .Is this because these are points and not a polygon?Is there any way to get the coordinates of the z?

Comment: Do you have depth buffering enabled?

Comment: Yes Martin I have enabled it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it can't be done. Any point x,y point on the screen can refer to any point along a given ray in the scene.

Given that you're drawing points, you probably want to use [select mode](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/selection.htm) to select a specific point, and then determine the coordinates of that point.

Comment: But he's trying to use the depth buffer value at x,y to determine the position along the ray. There's no fundamental reason why this can't be done.

Comment: @Martin Stone: In theory it could be done, but I don't know of a way that OpenGL supports actually doing it. I've already provided a link to what OpenGL does provide though.

Comment: Thank you so much for this link because I have a different RGB for every pixel,so this might really help me as I was not aware of this .I will have a look at it right away.

Comment: @ http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/picking/index.php3?color1                                                     http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/picking/index.php3?color2                        Thanks a lot for the Tip Jerry ,Color picking worked quite well..

Comment: What is the value range of your mouse coordinates - [0.0 .. 1.0] or [0 .. {screen width/screen height} - 1]?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling glReadPixels the wrong way. x, y, width and height must be GLint, not double. This has nothing to do with the format of the result glReadPixels returns. So you should pass the window coordinates for the mouse position and window sizes to glReadPixels (e.g. `glReadPixels (mouse_x, rect.Height() - mouse_y, rect.Width(), rect.Height(), GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,  GLfloat, &z);`. If mouse_x and mouse_y value range is [0.0 .. 1.0], you need to properly scale them in your call to glReadPixels (`rect.Width * mouse_x, rect.Height() * (1.0 - mouse_y`) If you get this right, imo your code should work as expected.